# Why can't I beatdown deadshot in batman arkham origins?

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-origins

I'm doing the Deadshot side mission in Arkham Origins, and after I take out the first round of goons using stealth take downs, I drop behind Deadshot, throw a cape stun, and there is no prompt to start the beat down. I can't hurt him in any meaningful way. What's the deal?!

Comment: Just Don't Rush!! With Every Move You Can Punch him 2 or 3 Times After That Back off Unless he block your attacks and kick you.

Comment: It won't even let me punch him. When I click to attack, nothing happens.

Comment: I Finish This Game For a While. But I think You should Stun him First

Comment: @pennstatephil are you sure you are talking about origins? The origins deadshot fight is counters and quicktime events, the Arkham City fight has goons and a sneak encounter.

Comment: Nevermind, I had him confused with deathstroke.

Answer (score 1):

You do not beatdown deadshot. You can only hurt him by repeatedly doing a stealth takedown (prompt while behind).

> To hurt Deadshot at first, stick to the gargoyles at the side of the room and then quietly drop down behind him and sneak up on him. Perform a silent takedown and then get out of there as fast as you can by grappling up to another gargoyle.
>
> Once you have taken Deadshot down a couple times, some more enemies will pour into the bank and Deadshot will now prefer to stick to the bottom level of the bank. Use the grates and vents around the lower floor to get a few more silent takedowns on Deadshot and he will then go and take a hostage in the middle of the bank.

[source](http://www.gamesradar.com/how-to-beat-deadshot-batman-arkham-origins/)

Comment: I used the cape stun/beatdown method and that worked fine for me, had to do a triple cape stun before the beatdown was initiated if I remember correctly...